# How to list tens of thousands of items from different vendors on our magento platform in a short period of time?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I have xls and csv files coming from the vendors (including products attributes) in different formats and different columns .

Each file includes 10000+ products
Is there is a way to enhance the data entry process to my magento store ?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/code4business/xmlimport is interesting for you, it's an XML adapter for the standard Magento import and it's usually easier to generate XML than to generate the weird Magento CSV format

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options.

Option 1 : Use the Standard Magento Import Process. The con of using this in your case is you need to format them to a specific standard.

Option 2 : Use Magmi. Personally I don't like this extension however others do. This extension is free
(https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

Option 3 : Use uRapidFlow. I have used this extension many times (and still do weekly). You can change the columns around and setup a separate profile for each vendor so when they update their file you have the settings already ready to go. This will also allow you to create attribute values on the fly (but not the physical attribute itself). This extension does cost money (https://secure.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/).

In any option, I would always recommend testing in a dev environment as importing is a powerful tool.

Comment: Many thanks, For option 1: I already use it .. but as you said it costs a lot of time to prepare the CSV files in magento standards. For option 2: I installed it on my test env but I'll give it try.  For option 3: Is there trial/demo version to test the full features of uRapidFlow ?....

Comment: I do know they do have a 1 week license. I would suggest just doing that. I will let you know that it is a very powerful tool and when used correctly it is a timesaver. However I would recommend to reach the whole manual. I also think if you ask them, they will show you a demo.